# vscode plugin latex-workshop doesn't generate tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, compiling, texstudio, build-system

my tableofcontents can be generated in texstudio, but in vscode with latex-workshop it can't be built, I tried several times. 
how to solve the problem?

Comment: I suggest you don't. I think more people in future will use vscode and they will probably run into this problem.

Answer (score 1):

why in vscode with latex-workshop the tableofcontents can't be built, because you set a configuration in settings.json:`"latex-workshop.latex.autoClean.run": "onBuilt"`.

This  configuration will clean up the files by default that include "*.aux" and "*.toc" ,which will disrupt the generate of the table of content.

so we can modify the configuration named "latex-workshop.latex.clean.fileTypes", to delete the "*.aux",and "*.toc",and the problem will be solved.

but  the "*.aux",and "*.toc", will be reserved. if you want clean them up, we can build twice before deletion.

you can modify the configuration named "latex-workshop.latex.recipes" ,insert a new object in to the array's end, the object will like this:

```
{"name": "xelatex*2",
            "tools": [
                "xelatex","xelatex"
            ]
}
```

the `name` is prepared for command panel choice, and the `tools` include the building tool sequence,here we can write the build tool twice ,and the latex-workshop will build file twice ,and after that , the clean up task will start,finally you get the tableofcontents and clean files both.

Comment: I didn't found latex-workshop.latex.recipes in Vscode.